# Gathering multiple attribute values from a number of list items on submit using Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, onclick

I have list items like so:

```
<ul id="band-list">
 <li data-band-id = '3' data-order = '1'>Text</li>
 <li data-band-id = '4' data-order = '2'>Text</li>
 <li data-band-id = '1' data-order = '3'>Text</li>
 <li data-band-id = '7' data-order = '4'>Text</li>
</ul>

<a href='#' id='createArray'>Click me</a>
```

What I'd like to do is create a Javascript (I can't use jQuery) function that when I click the link will grab all the list items then add the two attribute values to a multi-dimensional array so I end up with something like:

```
var bandArr = [[3,1],[4,2],[1,3],[7,4]];
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind `event listener` for that anchor tag and select the required elements to be grabbed by using `querySelectorAll`, iterate over it and frame the array that you want with `Array.prototype.map`,

```
document.getElementById("createArray").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var res = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul#band-list > li")).map(function(itm) {
    return [itm.dataset["bandId"], itm.dataset["order"]];
  });
  console.log(res);
}, false);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/42v7003b/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event listener on click events for the anchor.
Then in the anchor's handler you get the `li` elements of the `ul`.
You do that using the `querySelector` method (to get the `ul` element, as it returns only one result) and `querySelectorAll` to get all `li`'s from list.

Things are simple then, in a for loop, you get  your hands on the attributes by using the `getAttribute` method on each `li` element.
You push each pair of attributes in the multidimensional array. In the example below, I push a new array for each attribute pair in the `multiDimensionalArray` array.
I've parsed the attribute values to integers, as the `getAttribute` method returns a string result (from your description I assume that you want integer values for each pair).

Sample code:

```
(function(){
  document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var ul = document.querySelector("#band-list"),
        lis = ul.querySelectorAll("li"),
        length = lis.length,
        multiDimensionalArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
      multiDimensionalArray.push(
        [
          parseInt(lis[i].getAttribute("data-band-id")), 
          parseInt(lis[i].getAttribute("data-order"))
        ]);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(multiDimensionalArray));
  });
})();
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zQzqne) to run the code above.